# How can I filter jQuery Datatables when using input fields for data modification?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using jquery datatables to show the date of students but when i want to modify it i show the table with the values as inputs like this:
`<input type="text" name="ralum" value="<?echo $ralum ?>" required>`
So they can be change but when I want to search it doesnt work whereas if i print the value withouth being in an input it filters the data correctly.
How can i filter the data despite being the fields into inputs?

I use these resources:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

I tried this js from this [page](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-search-and-order-by-input-or-select-elements/),but it gives me an error because this tries to initialises the datatable again when i have done it previously calling this js into my html head tag:
`<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>`

I want the fields to be filtered despite being or not into an input.Any help I'm really thankful and forgive my poor english.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] in your question. A MRE is the smallest amount of code (and data) needed to demonstrate your specific problem. We should be able to copy/paste the MRE code, and run it without needing to make any significant changes.

Comment: "_I want the fields to be filtered despite being or not into an input_" - well, that is what the linked solution in your question already does. What is stopping you from changing your code to match how that example works? Show us your code.

Comment: @andrewJames I just have the link in the html head tag and the table where i print the data,but when i add the code from this page it gives me this error https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3

Comment: Yes - you mentioned that in your question. You have to _adapt_ your code to use this approach. But you have not shown us any of your code, so we cannot help you. Please provide a [mre]. See my first comment.